# Campaign analysis in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I am doing campaign analysis and the objective of campaigns is to convert lead into customer. I want to see how many leads are exposed to how many campaigns in terms of percentages before they convert to customer.

Below is the sample data where there are four unique lead.
abc has seen three campaigns, efg has seen two campaigns and so on and so forth

[image]

I want to show in pie chart may be something like below in tableau where out of 4 leads 2 leads has seen 1 campaign each so 50%, 1 lead has seen 2 campaigns so 25% and 1 lead has seen 3 campaign so another 25%
[image]

Comment: just to be clear, you're asking how to create that chart using tableau calculated field?

Comment: @ Fabio Fantoni - Yes...from the sample data set that I shared

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you have to find how many campaigns have been exposed for each Lead, **Count Campaign**:

```
{ FIXED [Lead id] : COUNT([Campaign])}
```

Since you want to breakdown your pie with this value, you need to convert this calculated field into a dimension.

In order to calculate the % you're looking for, you need just an additional step; **Metric**:

```
COUNTD([Lead id]) / attr({ FIXED : COUNTD([Lead id])})
```

Doing so you're going to compare each value to the total distinct value of your Lead (4)

[image]