# Campaign performance in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I am doing campaign analysis in Tableau where I want to see the percentage of leads that has seen 1 campaign,percentage of leads that has seen two campaign and so on in pie chart filter by month and region before they convert to customer.

For e.g in below sample data set there are 5 leads in February of which only lead id abc has seen two campaigns and rest four has seen one campaigns. So the view will be pie chart where 20%(1 out of 5) of lead has seen two campaigns and rest 80% has seen 1 campaigns. If March is selected then pie chart will be 100% one  campaign as there is only 1 lead.

If in region filter US is selected then there are three unique leads(abc,efg,klm) in february and view will be pie chart with 33% lead has seen two campaigns and rest two i.e 77% has seen 1 campaign.

I got idea from the link here but not able to do it when month and region filter is added.
[Campaign analysis in Tableau](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64220126/campaign-analysis-in-tableau/64223939#64223939)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add two calculated fields *both LOD*, as detailed below-

`Campaigns per Lead` as

```
{ FIXED [Lead id] : COUNT([Campaign])}
```

'Measure_val` as

```
COUNTD([Lead id]) / ATTR({ FIXED : COUNTD([Lead id])})
```

Format `Measure_val` as per cent in number format.

**Add your filters to view, add both filters to CONTEXT by right clicking them** (Note: *In order to have filters calculated before LOD calculation.  Normal filter calculates the view after LOD fields are calculated*).  **Check whether filters have been greyed out.**
[image: Screenshot]

Convert `Campaign per Lead` to dimension by right clicking it.

Add `Measure_val` to size, angle and text(for label-optional) and `Campaign per Lead` to color and text(optional again) and you're done.

[image: Desired Output]

Do tell if it worked.

Comment: @ Anil - It works only when month and region are not added as filter. When month is added as filter and March is selected it should give 100% to 1 as there is one lead in march seeing one campaign.But it shows 20% and that too to 2 campaigns

Comment: @joy_1379 have you added the filters to context?

Comment: @joy_1379, Check my edited solution/walkthrough.  Please vote if it worked!

Comment: It worked. Thanks a ton. Can you suggest where to learn more about LOD?

Comment: I learnt it from Tableau itself.  Their training modules/learning paths are great. By the way you can see this blog too https://www.tableau.com/about/blog/LOD-expressions