# Last touch marketing campaign view in tableau

Tags: tableau-api

In campaign analysis I want to view in Tableau what is the last campaigns that a lead has seen in a particular month and region. A lead may saw multiple campaigns.

For e.g.  in sample data set below Lead id abc has seen two campaigns – webnair, email  and last one is webnair.

Lead id efg  also has seen two campaigns webnair and email and webnair  is the last one. Lead id fgh has seen one campaign - Tradeshow

So in filter(month and region will be in filter) when February and US  is selected the view will be a bar plot showing  webnair  as count 2 and tradeshow as count 1. This will give an idea of which campaigns happens mostly before the lead converts to customer.

[image]

Had some insights here [Campaign performance in Tableau](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64433495/campaign-performance-in-tableau/64438879?noredirect=1#comment113989001_64438879). Tried replicating here with some changes but no luck so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like earlier ones this one is also not difficult.

Create `Desired_field` by adding a calculated field as

```
if [Month] = {fixed[Lead Id]: MAX([Month])} then 1 else 0 END
```

Create a view like the screenshot. (**Note: Don't forget to add filters to context!**)

Please note that in case of UK, and if FYU the two campaigns are on same date.  This will count both campaigns in the view in case of Feb and UK are selected.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: For UK in february it makes sense to show both the campaign as last touch and it worked out that way. Thanks. Learning from the blog you shared earlier https://www.tableau.com/about/blog/LOD-expressions

Comment: this one is basic https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_calculatedfields_lod_overview.htm